# How to know whether it is abstraction or inheritance by viewing the code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, inheritance, abstract-class

I have bit confused with the way that c# uses for abstraction and inheritance.
For an example : Abstract Class looks like

```
abstract class ShapesClass
{
    abstract public int Area();
}


class Square : ShapesClass //USES :
{
    int side = 0;
    public Square(int n)
    {
        side = n;
    }
    // Area method is required to avoid 
    // a compile-time error. 
    public override int Area()
    {
        return side * side;
    }

    static void Main() 
    {
        Square sq = new Square(12);
        Console.WriteLine("Area of the square = {0}", sq.Area());
    }
}
```

Inherited one looks like,

```
public class WorkItem
{
    private static int currentID;

    //Properties. 
    protected int ID { get; set; }
    protected string Title { get; set; }
    protected string Description { get; set; }
    protected TimeSpan jobLength { get; set; }

    public WorkItem()
    {
        ID = 0;
        Title = "Default title";
        Description = "Default description.";
        jobLength = new TimeSpan();
    }
}

public class ChangeRequest : WorkItem //This also uses :
{
    protected int originalItemID { get; set; }
}
```

So how to differentiate?

Comment: Look at the parent class, and see if it is abstract or not

Comment: This is not a case of either/or.  Both are examples of inheritance.  In the first case the base class is abstract.  In the second case the base class is not abstract.  Abstract classes are clearly declared as such (ie: with the `abstract` keyword).  What else is there to say?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can go through the following site. You'll get a clear idea

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/378919/Exact-difference-between-Inheritance-and-Abstracti

Comment: This is not an answer, it's just a link.  Things like this should be left as a comment.

Comment: The OP is not asking what the difference between the two is. Also, link only answers are not accepted here, as the link might break rendering your answer useless. This answer would have been better suited as a comment, if anything at all

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot instance a abstract class, it requires the child class implement the methods. The second sample, is a simple sample of inherits.

`ChangeRequest` will have all properties and methods of the `WorkItem` (as base class in this case). If you want to override some property or method, you have to declare it as `virtual` in the `Workitem` class.